# LINQ contain each element of all groups?

Tags: c#, linq

i have this match conditiond:

```
            var matchConditions = new long[][] 
                { 
                    new long[] { 109, 145 }, //color Id
                    new long[] { 202 }, // province Id
                    new long[] { 303, 309, 317, 318 }, //options Id
                };
```

each of them is id of a different group, for example first nested array is for color.
and i need to know which products meet color id 109 or 145, second one is for something else.
i mean i want to get all products that meet any item of all each group,

{color 109 *or* 145 - **and** - province 202 - **and** - option 303 *or* 309 *or* 317 *or* 318}

i tried:

```
matchConditions.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Any(j => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listFieldId).Contains(j)))
```

and

```
matchConditions.All(x => x.Any(j => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listFieldId).Contains(j)))
```

but none of them work

**EDIT:**
before now i had this query:

```
var adsWithRelevantadFields =
from adField in cwContext.tblAdFields
join ads in cwContext.tblAds on adField.adId equals ads.id
where (prvId == 0 && ads.tabId == tabId) ||
(prvId != 0 & ctsId.Value == 0 && ads.provinceId == prvId & ads.tabId == tabId) ||
(prvId != 0 & ctsId.Value > 0 && ads.provinceId == prvId & ads.cityId == ctsId.Value & ads.tabId == tabId)
where ads.endDate >= theToDay
where ads.conditionId == 1
where ads.payed == true                                                       
group adField by adField.adId into adAdFields                                 
where searchIds.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listFieldId).Contains(i))
```

this work well, but now i need to search more options that grouped as i showed, so i need to    add "&&" to end of query to search these new items, that is my question.

**EDIT2**
let's suppose i have some lists(color, who produce, options, where, ....) now when i want to  add a new product, add proper attribute in these format(productId, attributeId), so for example i have (1,109 - 1,202 - 1, 303 ...) and (2,109 - 2,202 - 2,318...) ...

so as i grouped each product(ads in real), i need just check which products grop:
{color 109 *or* 145 - **and** - province 202 - **and** - option 303 *or* 309 *or* 317 *or* 318}

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the product class?

Comment: Is matchConditions.Length always == 3 ?

Comment: i updated my questions, adfields are grouped of my products details

Comment: @mrlucmorin, no, it is dynamic.

Comment: @mohammadadibi so is it always a multiple of 3 ? I'm trying to understand your setup.

Comment: @mrlucmorin in this example i whant to know: colors are 109 or 145 and..., but in real matchConditions is dynamic and can 6,7 or more length, and each part of matchConditions can have dynamic values, for example color is 109 or 145 or ...

Comment: @mohammadadibi but how do you know which group of Id is associated with color for example ? Seems like color is in the 100, province in the 200 and option in the 300. Is that how it works ?

Comment: @mrlucmorin all matchConditions are unique, so if i wanted to know all ads that have colorId == 100, that was simple, but i don't know how to check in each category, i need somthing like for each or nested for in linq(suppose ads are my products)

Comment: @mohammadadibi How do you know, that `matchConditions[0]` should match `colorId`, `matchConditions[1]` should match `privinceId`, etc?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek hi MarcinJuraszek, i looking for you! let me edit my question again.

Comment: as i explain in edit2 i have grouped adfield, and colorId, proviceId... are unique so i just need each ad group has at least one of the matchcondition part, in this example: each adfields(that grouped by adId) has idValue(not colorId) 109 or 145, and so ...

Comment: I have to say that: I have no idea what you're asking for... Sorry, I cannot help you this time.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek if i want just check colors this work, searchIdsParalel.Any(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listFieldId).Contains(i)), but now i want to check many attributes.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek is it possible to groupby match conditions and use above command?

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
adAdFields.Where(x => matchConditions[0].Contains(x.colorId)
                  &&  matchConditions[1].Contains(x.provinceId)
                  && matchConditions[2].Contains(x.optionsId))
          .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you but my match conditions are variable, it can be more than 3, this is just an example

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to grain you query, how about to build this query - step by step, in that case you can improve readability of your code and check availibility of all conditions.

Look at this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var adAdFields = new List<AdAdField>
        {
            new AdAdField {colorId = 109, optionsId = 303, provinceId = 202},
            new AdAdField {colorId = 145, optionsId = 309, provinceId = 2},
            new AdAdField {colorId = 3, optionsId = 317, provinceId = 3},
            new AdAdField {colorId = 4, optionsId = 318, provinceId = 4}
        }.AsQueryable();

        var matchConditions = new long[][] 
            { 
                new long[] { 109, 145 }, //color Id
                new long[] { 202 }, // province Id
                new long[] { 303, 309, 317, 318 }, //options Id
            };

        var result1 = adAdFields.Where(x => matchConditions[0].Contains(x.colorId)
                              && matchConditions[1].Contains(x.provinceId)
                              && matchConditions[2].Contains(x.optionsId)).ToList();

        var query = adAdFields;

        if (matchConditions[0].Length > 0)
            query = query.Where(x => matchConditions[0].Contains(x.colorId));

        if (matchConditions[1].Length > 0)
            query = query.Where(x => matchConditions[1].Contains(x.provinceId));

        if (matchConditions[2].Length > 0)
            query = query.Where(x => matchConditions[2].Contains(x.optionsId));
        //below will be other possible conditions....


        var result2 = query.ToList();
        //result2 and result1 ARE SAME!!!
    }
}

public class AdAdField
{
    public int colorId { get; set; }
    public int provinceId { get; set; }
    public int optionsId { get; set; }
}
```

IQueriable will add conditions to query, eventually in the end of query you will call `.ToList()`, and it forces orm to generate appropriate sql. Until this time you just building query.

Comment: my attributes(color, options,...) are dynamic. i think i must groupby matchconditions but how, idon't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic linq , to construct a linq query similar to the one in @Selman22 answer, with varied number of conditions. Basically, A linq query is composed of a tree with expressions in it.
Dynamic LINQ means you build the tree, well - dynamically, which gives you more power creating the queries.

You can use PredicateBuilder to do so, or use a ready made library such as dynamic-query-library.
See:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231706/Dynamic-query-with-Linq

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: i couldn't undrestand these links, would you direct me more,